# Axios: wait till promise is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Using axios in React where I am calling an endpoint to fetch JWT token as follows

```
fetchJwtToken = async () => {
        await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/authenticate',
            {
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }
        ).then(
            (res) => {
                console.log("JWT token fetch")
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({jwtToken: res.data.jwt})
            }
        )
    }
```

and then calling this function as follows

```
processImage = () => {
        this.fetchJwtToken();
        console.log(this.state.jwtToken)
        //use the token to make further calls
}
```

The function returns a pending promise due to which I think the await completes its execution. This results in empty JWT token to be set in the state.

I want to wait till the token is returned so that I can use it for further calls

How to make it wait till axios returns a fulfilled promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither answer address the whole issue

You don't need fetchJwtToken to be async, you can simply return the promise

```
fetchJwtToken = () => {
        return axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/authenticate',
            {
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }
        ).then(
            (res) => {
                console.log("JWT token fetch")
                console.log(res)
                this.setState({jwtToken: res.data.jwt})
            }
        )
    }
```

or, if it is async

```
fetchJwtToken = async () => {
    const res = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:8080/authenticate',
        {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        }
    );
    console.log("JWT token fetch")
    console.log(res)
    this.setState({jwtToken: res.data.jwt})
}
```

either way, where you call it, if you need to wait as well

either

```
processImage = () => {
    this.fetchJwtToken().then(() => {
        console.log(this.state.jwtToken)
        //use the token to make further calls
    }
}
```

or

```
processImage = async () => {
    await this.fetchJwtToken();
    console.log(this.state.jwtToken)
    //use the token to make further calls
}
```

Your choice, but that will now work as you require

Note: you can use either of the first two `fetchJwtToken` with either of the two `processImage` - which ever you want

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `await / async`, I suggest you change your code to this:

```
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/authenticate',
        {
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password'
        });

console.log(response.data);
this.setState({jwtToken: response.data.jwt})
```

If you're more familiar with `.then`, the above `await` is equivalent to doing this:

```
axios.post(...).then((response)=>{})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must send your promise in a variable like this and if you use `await` better you don't use `.then` you must doing like this :

```
fetchJwtToken = async () => {
        let anyThing = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8080/authenticate',
            {
                username: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            }
        )
        console.log(anyThing)
    }
```

Comment: yes your advise is correct but it does not matter use .then with await with just use one of them

Comment: yes there isn't any low but for Clean code better use just one and for catching error use try catch